# Rails 5 DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Installed Rails 5. Thought things were fine, but can't create a db or start server. I get this error:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated.
>   Please change:
>
> Mime::HTML
>
> to:
>
> Mime[:html] . (called from  at
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/request.rb:7)
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated.
>   Please change:
>
> Mime::TEXT
>
> to:
>
> Mime[:text] . (called from  at
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/request.rb:7)
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated.
>   Please change:
>
> Mime::URL_ENCODED_FORM
>
> to:
>
> Mime[:url_encoded_form] . (called from  at
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/request.rb:7)

Not quite sure what to do here. Not sure where to change `Mime::HTML`. Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 19):

change Gemfile:
`gem 'web-console', '~> 3.0'`
bundle update

Comment: same issue with 5.0.0.beta4, upgrading to web-console 3.0 solved it. Thanks!

Comment: This solved these 3 warnings, but i have another one like "Please change `Mime::JSON` to `Mime[:json]`" can you point out which gem might be causing this, i dont want to update all my bundles. And thanks for the help